# Facebook : Unable to add new app domain in Facebook Developer Console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, developer-console

I am facing a strange issue in facebook developer console for adding a new domain in **APP DOMAIN TEXTBOX**.

**Scenario:**
I have already added 4 domains in **APP DOMAIN TEXTBOX** in facebook developer console for my app, but now when I am adding the 5th domain to link to my app it showing and Error is shown below.

> App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL
>   (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page
>   Tab URL. Please correct these domains: xyz.maindomain.com

As the error message is also clearly understood that the URL has to be part of the above-mentioned categories. But as I am done with all above provided categories where my URL's are appearing, I am not having the option to add the new URL for my new domain.

Can anyone suggest me that how can I add my new 5th domain??

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can’t. Facebook does not want you to use one and the same app on a multitude of domains - especially now after the Cambridge Analytica story broke. Specifying a different URL for all the platforms that accept one can give you more than one domain effectively - but it doesn’t allow for any arbitrary, unlimited number you might like.

Comment: It's nowhere mention in documentation in facebook anywhere. And for my app, I am already using 4 domains. but dunno how to add 5th one!